# NSScrollView Magnification Not Affecting Document View

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage, nsscrollview

My setup includes a NSScrollView with a customized NSImageView embedded via IB. I checked the box for the scrollview to allow magnification. But when I run the App I get this:

Original Image:
[image: Original Image]

When I pinch to zoom out (make the image smaller):
[image: Should be smaller]

When I pinch to zoom in (make the image bigger):
[image: Should be larger]

But is does not seem like the magnification is working as I expected. Am I missing something? It seems as if the embedded clip view is what is really changing. But the size of the document view (the image with with white background) is not really changing.

Comment: Are you using a layer-backed content view?

Comment: @insys, yes layer backed...

Comment: Just a note. If anybody is using *layer-hosting* view then you need to set the scale transform on your root view, AppKit will not do it for you.